# How is it possible to update curl to 7.88.0 on nginx Docker image?

Tags: docker, nginx

There is a security venerability on nginx Docker images due to the curl version being below 7.88.0 - https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2023-23914

There doesn't seem to be any nginx image that uses this version of curl

How would it be possible for me to manually update the version of curl?

Answer (score 0):

Solved using:

```
 1. curl -L -O https://curl.se/download/curl-7.88.0.tar.gz
 2. tar -xvf curl-7.88.0.tar.gz
 3. cd curl-7.88.0
 4. ./configure --without-ssl
 5. make
 6. make install
```